# Adding a link to MapBox Tooltip

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I really hope anyone of you are able to help me, as i've been on this for hours now without luck.

I'm using mapbox.com api to generate a map on my end, but i can't seem to be able to add links to it!.

So, if i for example do it like this:

```
properties: {
    title: 'Tooltip Title',
    description: '<a target="_blank" href="#modal"data-toggle="modal">Test</a>',
    'marker-size': 'large',
    'marker-color': '#35B070',
}
```

It will echo out the description as

```
<a>Test</a>
```

But if i do for an example

```
properties: {
    title: 'Tooltip Title',
    description: '<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/" data-toggle="modal">Test</a>',
    'marker-size': 'large',
    'marker-color': '#35B070',
}
```

It will echo out as:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/">Test</a>
```

Does anyone know how to manage this ?... Making me nuts...

Answer (score 1):

See the [sanitizer option](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.4.0/#L.mapbox.markerLayer) to markerLayer. HTML that goes through markers/mapbox.js is sanitized by default to prevent people from writing `href="javascript:evilXSSAttack()"`.